# Customise LinkedIn Follow click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, linkedin-api

I have integrated LinkedIn Login and also Follow button in my Asp.Net MVC website.

But I've to call a function after the click on Follow button. 
I have tried the following code. but it's not working

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    function myOnclickFunction(r) {
                        alert("click");
                        console.log(r);
                        // do something here
                    }

                    function myOnsucesssFunction(r) {
                        alert("success");
                        console.log(r);
                        // do something else here
                    }
                </script>
              <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
                    <script type="IN/FollowCompany"
                            data-id="1337"
                            data-jobtitle="Chief Cat Herder"
                            data-onclick="myOnclickFunction"
                            data-onsuccess="myOnsuccessFunction">
                    </script>
```

Anybody please help me